# Do class declaration and definition in header file get compiled on each include?

Tags: c++, compilation, header-files

If I do **not** separate a class declaration and definition, but put my class definition in a header file, then will this definition code get re-compiled for every source file that includes that header?

Comment: Presumably you're referring to defining member functions inside vs outside of the class definition. A class declaration (`class myclass;`) doesn't do much.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Correct, that is what I should have said.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's compiled once for every [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (from which an object file is then built.) Unless you're using some form of pre-compiled header functionality in your compiler.

The multiple inclusion guards you normally put in headers are there to avoid multiple compilation in the same translation unit only. Unless the compiled result of the header has been stored somewhere by the compiler's pre-compiled header mechanism, the header will need to be compiled again in the next translation unit.

This is one of the reasons why C++ code tends to compile much slower than C code, and why it's important to make proper use of forward declarations and avoid unneeded `#include` statements. I've seen cases where build times were cut in half just by using forward declarations instead of including the whole header.